# 10.0.0.0/8 : Routable or non-routable?

Tags: networking, ipv4, traceroute

Playing aroung with `tracert`, I don't really understand this :

[image]

From what I know, 10.0.0.0/8 addresses are meant for private use and are **not** routable. Then why my router allows the packets to go "outside" and my then even my ISP default gateway (105.104.0.4) forwards them too?

Comment: The [IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml) explains which networks are routable, and which are not, among other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private IP addresses are just normal addresses that we reserved for private use. They are routable just like any other unicast addresses. It's just that we don't allocate them to a single organisation but allow multiple organisations to use them in private.

Because they are normal addresses a default gateway will route them just fine. It's when you reach the default free zone (routers that don't have a default gateway but know the actual routes to all IP address blocks in use) that your packet can't travel any further because a route for it doesn't exist on the public internet.

At least, it shouldn't exist. There is nothing special about those addresses in a technical sense, so if routes are accidentally leaked or someone is running an experiment then even packets to private addresses might travel across the internet and accidentally reach somebody :-)